# Encoded URL gives Bad gateway 502

Tags: php, urlencode

I have very strange problem..

If I have this combination `"><` encoded like `%22%3E%3C` in URL I received 502 Bad Gateway on one server and no response on another.

I have never seen this behavior. This is normal HTTP request on PHP file that outputs editor for HTML code. Everything works fine if this combination doesn't show up.

Why is this happening?

Comment: maybe you should use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` and then `urlencode()`

Comment: Do you have any website protection installed? Some applications check for XSS and such before forwarding the request to the application.

Comment: there is no problem with these entities `%22%3E%3C` are you sure thats what the server gets? check your error_log files and post what you see there.

Comment: @aleation i will try this if nothing helps but as Sharky said this entities should work.

Comment: @Sharky there is no error recorder in error_log. I can't check what server gets because i receive none response from server. What i have noticed is that if i write URL like this file.php?var=test%22%3E%3Ctest and press enter in chrome url is changed to file.php?var=test"><test in address bar.. If I remove only one of this characters i get expected server response

Comment: @abdom make sure you have `magic_quotes_gpc` to `off` in your php.ini and please post your .htaccess

Comment: @Sharky magic_quotes are deprecated in 5.3. I have basic WordPress .htaccess file https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess (concerning file is not connected with WordPress)

Comment: If I use POST with same content it works fine, so that is solution for me in this case..